# Can the Carmichael Function be used with Proof By Infinite Descent in the following way?

Tags: solution-verification, infinite-descent, carmichael-function

I was reading up on the [Carmichael Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) and I had a question about its use.

Can it be used to show that if $x > 1$, then $n=1$ for:

$$2^m(2^x - 1) = 3^n(3^y - 1)$$

Here's the argument that I came up with.  Did I make a mistake?

Let:

- $m,x>1,n,y$ be integers

(1)  Assume that $n > 1$

(2)  $2^x \equiv 1 \pmod {3^n}$

(3)  From the Carmichael Function, $2^{\varphi(3^n)}$ is the least power of $2$ which is congruent to $1 \pmod {3^n}$ with $\varphi(3^n) = 2\times3^{n-1}$

(4)  It follows from [Lagrange's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)) that $2\times3^{n-1} | x$ so that there exists an integer $b$ such that:

$$2^m(2^x - 1) = 2^m(2^{2\times3^{n-1}b} - 1) =2^m(2^{3^{n-1}b}-1)(2^{3^{n-1}b}+1) = 3^n(3^y - 1)$$

(5) Since $n > 1$, it follows that $2\times3^{n-1} | (3^{n-1}b)$ and there exists $c \ge 1$ such that $2^{3^{n-1}b}-1 = 2^{3^{n-1}2c}-1 = (2^{3^{n-1}c} - 1)(2^{3^{n-1}c} + 1)$.

(6) Indeed, it appears to me that we have an example of [infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) since we can continue to repeat this same process without end since in each case $n > 1$ and this power must therefore be divisible by $\varphi(3^n)$

(7)  Therefore, we can reject our assumption at step(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your argument. First, with

> (3)  From the Carmichael Function, $2^{\varphi(3^n)}$ is the least power of $2$ which is congruent to $1 \pmod {3^n}$ with $\varphi(3^n) = 2 \times 3^{n-1}$

The Carmichael function, i.e., $\lambda(n)$, is the smallest positive integer where *all* integers $a$ coprime to $n$ have $a^{\lambda(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. However, for any specific coprime integer $a$, there may be smaller such exponents, with the smallest positive one being called the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) (note the Carmichael function value is the $\operatorname{lcm}$ of all of the multiplicative orders). Nonetheless, since $2$ to any odd power will be congruent to $2$ modulo $3$, the multiplicative order must be even, so since it must divide $\varphi(3^{n})$, it will be $2 \times 3^{k}$ for some $0 \le k \le n - 1$. Also, as I recall, there was a question fairly recently on this site which was basically equivalent to proving that the multiplicative order, in this case, is actually $2 \times 3^{n - 1}$.

Assuming this is correct, the next issue is with

> (5) Since $n > 1$, it follows that $2\times3^{n-1} | (3^{n-1}b)$ and there exists $c \ge 1$ such that $2^{3^{n-1}b}-1 = 2^{3^{n-1}2c}-1 = (2^{3^{n-1}c} - 1)(2^{3^{n-1}c} + 1)$.

From your $(4)$, you got that $2^m(2^{3^{n-1}b}-1)(2^{3^{n-1}b}+1) = 3^n(3^y - 1)$. Your step $(5)$ is correct *only* if $b$ is even. If $b$ is odd instead (note since each repeat of your $(4)$ and $(5)$ removes a factor of $2$ from the exponent, this will happen once all those even factors have been removed), then $2^{3^{n-1}b} - 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, and $3$ instead divides $2^{3^{n-1}b} + 1$. In this case, you can't split the result into another difference of squares, so you will not get your infinite descent you describe in your $(6)$.

One final issue is I don't see anywhere in your argument that $n \gt 1$ is actually used and makes a difference, i.e., the steps you wrote also seem to apply to the case where $n = 1$ as well, which does have solutions, e.g., $m = 3$, $x = 2$, $n = 1$ and $y = 2$.

Note that I believe your hypothesis is correct, but I'm not sure offhand how to prove it, or even if there is any current method available to do this. Although I only manually checked a few relatively small values, I also suspect that if the hypothesis is not true, the first counter-example may be quite large and difficult to find.

Comment: Thanks very much!  My assumption about $n > 1$ relates to a misunderstanding of the dofference between the Carmichael Function and the Multiplicative Order.  Now, I am clear.  :-)

Comment: @LarryFreeman You're welcome. I'm glad you've cleared up your misunderstanding. As for your hypothesis, as my updated answer states, I'm not sure if there is any current method available to prove it. Of course, if it's incorrect, as I also state, the first counter-example may be quite large. It may possibly even be more than current computer technology can deal with. Nonetheless, it's an interesting question, and I'll keep it in the back of my mind in case I get any interesting ideas to check on, or if I see anything which might help to resolve whether or not it is correct.